# Change bibliography title for extarticle class

Tags: babel, ukrainian

I use:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}


\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I obtain: "Література". How to change the bibliography title to be "Список використаних джерел" (including corresponding name for `\tableofcontents`)? I tried `\renewcommand\bibname{...}` and `\renewcommand\refname{...}`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using (a) the [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package with language option `ukrainian` and (b) the `extarticle` document class (which defines a macro called `\refname`), you should run

```
\addto\extrasukrainian{\renewcommand\refname{Список використаних джерел}}
```

to achieve your formatting objective.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\addto\extrasukrainian{\renewcommand\refname{Список використаних джерел}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want a line item for the bibliography to show up in the table of contents, I'd suggest employing the [tocbibind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package -- specifically, running `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks! a) without `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` I get strange characters instead "Список використаних джерел", maybe it's due to my old latex version on Linux, however, it's not so important; b) I used `\begin{thebibliography}{00}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Список використаних джерел}` before, but now I use your advice, `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`, as far as I understand the results are identical.

Comment: @misha.physics - I didn’t recommend against loading `fontenc`.

Comment: Yes, it was just my experiment.